# How to configure Qt with opengl dekstop option?

Tags: qt, opengl, desktop, configure

Just installed Qt 5.0.2 (qt-windows-opensource-5.0.2-mingw47_32-x86-offline; here I'll say "wow" for the cool interface of the IDE) and faced one warning and one error when tried to 'Run' the 'boxes' example:

> Qt was built with ANGLE, which provides only OpenGL ES 2.0 on top of DirectX 9.0c
>
> This example requires Qt to be configured with -opengl desktop

Searched in their wiki but didn't find what should I do to fix it :(

Anyone wanna throw some more light about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This example requires Qt to be configured with -opengl desktop

This refers to the `-opengl desktop` configuration option that can be passed to Qt's build system when configuring the library build. You did install a precompiled version of Qt and can't change much about its build options. You'll have to download the Qt sources and build them to your configuration needs.

Comment: So ... if I don't want to build it, the better choice is to download qt-windows-opensource-5.0.2-msvc2010_32_opengl-x86-offline.exe ...
Can you explain me what are the conf options, if I want to write an cross-platform app (for android and win/linux). Using mingw I assume?

Thanks in advance